# How to implement a multilingual website with two other domains?

Tags: magento2, multistore

I have 2 domains: domain.com and domain.in
Server: ubuntu 16, nginx 1.10, magento 2.
Same product for both store, but diferent discription, url... The official documentation does not have this information with nginx config. 
Try this: 
Creat store view this code in. After:
./magento cron:run

Change config:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    domain.com default;
    domain.in in;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.in;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.in$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com domain.in;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/domain.com/html;
    set $MAGE_MODE default;

    location = /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/domain.com/html/robots.txt;
    }

    location = /sitemap.xml {
        alias /var/www/domain.com/html/sitemap.xml;
    }

    include /var/www/domain.com/html/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Insert to nginx.conf.sample:

```
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
```

Site not open. Error: 2016/10/30 09:37:50 [error] 6345#6345: *29624 access forbidden by rule, client: 000.000.00.000, server: domain.com, request: "POST /app/etc/config.php HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement if you have same categories, product, prices for every store. I suggest you to create different store views.

1. Default - domain.com
2. Second Store View - domain.in

Your can create store views from

```
Stores > All Stores > Create Store View
```

You can then configure the base url for each store view from configuration

```
Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Base Urls and Base Url (secure)
```

From store scope selection select your particular stores and change there respective urls.

You can change same product and set there description for each store views.

Comment: Thank you! I know this, but I have problem with nginx config maybe...